# Add Hibernate to STS Dynamic Web Project

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a Dynamic Web Project which I am developing using STS.

I want to add Hibernate to it. Is it a matter of adding the necessary jar files to the project manually, or is there some trick that I am missing that will just allow me to "Add Hibernate" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the jars.

- If it is no maven project then copy the jars to: `webapp/WEB-INF/lib`
- If you use maven then add the hibernate dependencies to your pom

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

Comment: Thanks Ralph - complete newbie to Maven, so any pointers as to how to do that?

Comment: @DaveHowes: see my extended answer