# Servlet not found maven project ?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, servlets

so i don't know if this is a duplicate or not but i searched for a similar error in vain,
here is the thing, i'm new to J2EE i started a project (without hibernate) to assimilate the basics, and it worked just fine, now that i went to hibernate, i can't solve the problem
the problem being i can't run servlets, i keep getting the 404 error.

Connection.java

```
@WebServlet("/Connection")
public class Connection extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Connection() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String mdp = request.getParameter("mdp");
    try {
        Utilisateurs.Connection(login,mdp);
        if (Utilisateurs.conected_admin)
        response.sendRedirect("index_admin.jsp");
        else
            response.sendRedirect("Failed.jsp");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

```html
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Connectez vous !</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action ="Connection" method="POST">
    Login<input type="text" name="login"><br><br>
     Mot de passe<input type="password" name="mdp"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Se Connecter">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem has been answered before in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474346/what-values-can-a-jsp-form-action-take The answer to that question will help with your problem.

Comment: after reading the thread you mentioned i still can't solve the problem.
I forgot to mention that when tested in a basic Dynamic web project it works just fine but the same codes under hibernate doesn't which is weird in my opinion.
Also i get the little "x" (as for error) under Java ressources of my project, but i don't know where the error is.

Comment: Is this in an IDE? Eclipse?

Comment: Yes i'm using Eclipse neon

Comment: It might be easier to add the Hibernate jars as a library to the Dynamic Web project. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227792/add-hibernate-to-sts-dynamic-web-project